# Algolia Faceted Search to Show all Facet Options

Tags: algolia

I'm using facets with Algolia using the js client.  As an example, if I have facets for colors and sizes, and I pick Red and Large, I can get the results with something like:

```
index.search("shirts", {
  "facets": "*",
  "hitsPerPage": 10,
  "facetFilters": [
    "color:Red",
    "size:Large",
  ],
  "maxValuesPerFacet": 100
});
```

That works fine, showing just the Red and Large facets in the result:

```
Color:
Red

Size:
Large
```

But I would like to be able to show all of the possible options for each facet and just highlight the selected one.  Something like:

```
Color:
Red *selected*
Blue
Green

Size:
Large *selected*
Small
Medium
```

Is there a way to do this in Algolia with one search query and using regular facets (not disjunctive)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to handle facets easily is to use the [Algolia JS Helper](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-helper-js), additionally to the [JS API Client](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-js)

That one offers an elegant way to manage regular facets, disjunctive facets, but also hierarchical facets.

Answer (score 1):

You can only achieve such a behavior with disjunctive faceting as you need to have several queries:

- first query without the filter to compute the counts on each facets
- second query with the filter applied to have the count after application of filters

The disjunctive faceting is generating those queries for you so you won't have to deal with them.

Comment: what is the difference between filtering and faceting?